# how do function implements Generics in java

Tags: java, generics

I am preparing for [OCJP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sun_Certified_Professional#Oracle_Certified_Professional_Java_SE_Programmer_.28formerly_the_Sun_Certified_Java_Programmer.29). I found a question in dump

```
import java.util.*;
 public class G1 {
 public void takeList(List<? extends String> list) {
   // insert code here
 }
}
```

**Which three code fragments, inserted independently at line 6, will compile? (Choose three.)**

```
 A. list.add("foo");
 B. Object o = list;
 C. String s = list.get(0);
 D. list = new ArrayList<String>();
 E. list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

**Answer: B,C,D**

I have a query that if `List<? extends String` that means it matches with String class and all the subclass of String class.

Can anyone justify the answer shown here?

Comment: java.lang.String is final class.

Comment: option A is also valid, I guess

Comment: i tried to run the code option A gives error

Comment: This should solve your query http://www.coderanch.com/t/264097/java-programmer-SCJP/certification/prob-generics

Comment: Take a look at, e.g. http://groups.google.com/group/juglugano/browse_thread/thread/c11531309ed37646?pli=1 — it should probably explain things a bit.

Comment: Oh option A is compile error.

Comment: `final` could be removed from `String` (it wont be, but in theory could, but who would want a language that depended upon reasoning like that? Does it help to have `<? extends String>` in code you wrote?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A is incorrect, because your list could be a `List<SomeStringSubClass>`, and it would thus be invalid to add a String to it. (I know String is final, but the compiler doesn't care about it here).

E is incorrect because a `List<Object>` can't be assigned to a `List<? extends String>`, obviously, since the objects contained by a `List<Object>` don't necessarily are of type String or of a subclass of String.

The other three ones are OK:

- B is OK because everything except primitives is a an Object in Java
- C is OK because a `List<? extends String>` contains instances of String, or instances of a subclass of String. And an instance of a sublcass is also an instance of the superclass.
- D is OK because an `ArrayList<String>` is a `List<String>`, and a `List<String>` is also a `List<? extends String>`

Comment: I am unable to understand why list.add("foo") can't be used.Can u hep

Comment: Let's take an example with something other than String. A `List<? extends Animal>` means "a List of some class that is Animal or extends Animal, but we don't know which type". So it might be a `List<Animal>`, or a `List<Chicken>`, or a `List<Dog>`. If it's a `List<Dog>`, and you are able to do `list.add(new Chicken())` or `list.add(new Animal())`, then the type-safety of the list is completely broken, since it's supposed to contain only Dog instances. It's thus illegal to do so.

Comment: But if the type safety is an issue then why List<? extends Animal> is used.It can be simply List<Animal>

Comment: why list.get(0) will not create a problem

Comment: It's useful when a method must do the same this for a List<Dog>, a List<Chicken>, or a List<Animal>. Such a method won't add anything to the list, but it might iteratre through it, get its elements (which are all Animal instances, etc.) list.get(0) returns what is at the first index of the List. And it's guaranteed that it's an Animal. It could be a Dog or a Chicken. But a Dog is an Animal. And a Chicken also is an Animal. That's what inheritance means.

Answer (score 1):

```
A. `list.add("foo");`
```

Won't compile as you will only be able to insert `null` into this list

```
 B. Object o = list;
```

Compiles, as list is an object

```
C. String s = list.get(0);
```

Compiles, as every element in the list is guaranteed to be a string object or theorically subclass of it (practically not possible as String is a final class and cannot be extended ).

```
 D. list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Compiles, as every element in the list is guaranteed to be a string object.

```
 E. list = new ArrayList<Object>();
```

Won't compile , as not every object is a string

```
Keep in mind that String is a final class and cannot be extended.
```

Answer (score 0):

`List` is an `Object`, so B is valid.

Whatever is stored in the list can be upcast to a String, and so C is valid.

In generics "`<? extends String>`" covers subclasses of `String`, of which there are none, *and* String itself, so D is valid.

Likewise, "`<? super String>`" means `String` or any of `String's` inheritance tree, e.g. `Object`, `CharSequence`, `Serializable`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

A will not compile as the list could be a list of things which extend String.  Generics takes no notice of whether a class is final.

A simpler example is

```
public void takeList(List<? extends Number> list) {
   // insert code here
   list.add(1.0); // not allowed.
   Number n = list.get(0); // allowed.
}

// you could call it with
takeList(new List<BigInteger>());
```